# Receiving unknown exception when trying to perform a coordinate transform with PyQGIS

Tags: coordinate-system, pyqgis

I'm trying to create a script that will use the decimal degree coordinates of point features. To do this, I want to perform a coordinate transformation on features whose coordinates are in meters. In the code below, I get the active layer and store its coordinate system ([UTM zone 18N](http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/nad83-utm-zone-18n/)), then choose an NAD83 geographic coordinate system (EPSG:5498), and construct a QgsCoordinateTransform. I then attempt various methods of executing the transformation, with bost `QgsCoordinateTransform.transform(QgsPointXY)` and `QgsGeometry.transform(QgsCoordinateTransform)`, but all of them result in `Exception: unknown`.

```
Python Console 

li = iface.activeLayer()

liearth = ifacel.activeLayer().crs()

flatearth = QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem(5498)

lipts = [f for f in li.getFeatures()]

toflat = QgsCoordinateTransform(liearth, flatearth, QgsProject.instance())

for f in lipts:
  gPoint = toflat.transform(f.geometry().asPoint())
  print(gPoint)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/code.py", line 91, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<input>", line 2, in <module>
Exception: unknown


fPts = [f.geometry().asPoint() for f in lipts]

type(fPts[0])
<class 'qgis._core.QgsPointXY'>

QgsCoordinateTransform(li.crs(), flatearth, QgsProject.instance()).transform(fPts[0])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/code.py", line 91, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
Exception: unknown
type(fPts[0])
<class 'qgis._core.QgsPointXY'>

fGeo = [f.geometry() for f in lipts]
type(fGeo)
<class 'list'>
type(fGeo[0])
<class 'qgis._core.QgsGeometry'>

newpoint = fGeo[0]

newpoint
<qgis._core.QgsGeometry object at 0x114d5edc8>

newpoint.asPoint()
(592932,4.52942e+6)

newpoint.transform(QgsCoordinateTransform(li.crs(), flatearth, QgsProject.instance()))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/code.py", line 91, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
Exception: unknown
```

The only helpful detail that I've been able to find online on this is [someone who also received an unknown exception](https://issues.qgis.org/issues/17600) a few months ago a little before QGIS 3 was released. However, hey were able to fix the issue using a QgsRectangle, which I cannot do.

Comment: Do you really need 5498 which is a compound CRS of NAD83 + NAVD88? What about using 4269, the 2D geographic version of NAD83?

Comment: @mkennedy this rectified the problem. I will add this as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Since EPSG:5498 is a CRS with a vertical datum, the transformation fails. Using EPSG:4269, which is the same as 5498 but without the vertical datum, the transformation should be successful.